# Deserialize JSON Stream with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I recently switched from using SOAP to JSON. I now have a problem with the performance because it takes about 26 seconds to deserialize the JSON stream on my WP7 device.

Therefore I thought about using Json.net instead of DataContractJsonSerializer.

However, I was not able to find much information about this.

I use a webclient and then OpenReadAsync, so I have a Stream as e.Result.

How can I turn that stream into an object using Json.net?

Should I maybe use DownloadStringAsync instead?

This is the Code that currently works:

```
//string URL = ""; //Actual URL to JSON is here

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(URL, UriKind.Absolute));
```

And the event handler:

```
void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JSONObject), null);
     JSONObject data = serializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as JSONObject;
}
```

JSONObject is the response object of the service's SOAP endpoint, but both endpoints return the same data.

This works fine and I can go on and parse data just like I parsed the SOAP response, but I would like it do deserialize faster.

Answer (score 3):

In order to deserialize you'll need the whole JSON. It may be better to use DownloadStringAsync and once you've received the entire JSON string, you can deserialize it.

Then in your `DownloadStringCompleted` you can pass in the class you want to deserialize it to. For example, if you are receiving JSON like:

```
{ name: "smoak", title: "super awesome" }
```

Then you need to create a class with those properties:

```
class SomeClassName 
{
    publc string name { get;set;}
    public string title { get;set; }
}
```

and pass it to the JsonConvert:

```
var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClassName>(e.Result);
Console.WriteLine(deserializedObj.name);
```

Comment: OK but then how do I deserialize it? I tried this:
JsonObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject >(e.Result); but I get this error: Cannot deserialize JSON array into type [...]. However when I use OpenReadAsync and use the built in JSON deserilization is works.

Comment: You have to pass in the class you want to deserialize it to. For example, if you are receiving JSON like:

{ name: "smoak", title: "super awesome" }

Then you need to create a class with those properties:

class SomeClassName {
publc string name { get;set;}
public string title { get;set; }
}

and pass it to the JsonConvert:

var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClassName>(e.Result);

Comment: Yes I already did that. The weird thing is that is works fine with OpenReadAsync + built in JSON serialization, but when I try DownloadStringAsyc + Json.net it does not work.

Comment: Looking back at your comment it looks like you are receiving an array of objects in your JSON. Try using an array with DeserializeObject like so: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject[]>(e.Result);

Comment: That does not work either although the error message is now "Cannot deserialize JSON object into type [...]". Is the problem maybe that my Object it the SOAP's Response object? The API I use offers both SOAP and JSON endpoints, so I decided to use the response objects from the SOAP API. As I said, it works with OpeanReadAsync etc. but it is too slow.

Comment: Are the SOAP and JSON responses different in any way? If they are you'll need two separate classes one for the SOAP response and one for the JSON response. I can't really provide more insight without seeing code and response examples.

Comment: They return the same identical data. I have updated my original question with the working code.